# How to populate expandablelistview's parent and child with same List<Object>

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a list of object and i want to populate ExpandableListView with data of these objects . I want to show one property of object in parent of ExpandableListView and to show another property of object in child of ExpandableListView. Can any one tell me how can i do this, my codes are like these;

When i use these codes, only one parent row shows at ExpandableList, bu List has more than one object.

```
public class textExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public List<textexplain> tmpTextExp;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return extCrmActions.size();
}

public textExpAdapter (Context context, List<textexplain> tmpTextExp)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.tmpTextExp= tmpTextExp;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

    return tmpTextExp.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return tmpTextExp.get(childPosition);

}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {

    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {

    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    textexplain action = (textexplain) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if(view == null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crmactions_elv_head,null);
    }

    final TextView txtCrmActionHeaderClm1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCrmActionHeaderClm1);
    final TextView txtCrmActionHeaderClm2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCrmActionHeaderClm2);

    SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    txtCrmActionHeaderClm1.setText(sdFormat.format(action.ACTIONDATE));
    txtCrmActionHeaderClm2.setText(action.STEXT);

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    textexplain action = (textexplain) tmpTextExp.get(groupPosition);
    if(view==null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crmactions_elv_bottom, null);
    }

    final TextView txtCrmActionBottomText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtCrmActionBottomText);
    txtCrmActionBottomText.setText(action.LTEXT);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Use 2 arrays one that stores the values for parent view and another for child. Use the first array to display the content of the parents and the other for child. You can use 2D array

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a way but i wonder if there is another solution for using same array.